# Using a bat file how to select file from directory for processing if it's of certain type

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I'm using the command line interface version of MediaInfo to extract several parameters (to keep the code brief I  only show format and duration below) from several hundred small video tutorials to process them for other uses.

I use a .bat file that gathers the parameters, pipes them to a txt file and then opens the file in Notepad:

```
f:\path\mediainfo.exe "--Inform=Video;%%Format%%\r\n%%Duration/String%%" "tutorial.mp4" > out.txt

sleep 1

start out.txt
```

As it stands now I have to cut and paste the actual video name into the batch file (file name is "tutorial.mp4" in code above) because I don't know how to programmatically get that parameter into the mediainfo command.

So, my question is, since the video files will always be either .avi or .mp4, is there a way to add some code to the bat file to look for a file in the directory the bat file is in and if it's either of those two types insert the file name into the first line as I have it now?  There will only ever be one single video file in the sub directory and it will be either a .avi or a .mp4.  It's remotely possible that there might be other file types in the subdirectory so for this reason I can't say "pick the ONLY file in the subdirectory and insert it into the bat file".

I'm wondering if something along this line added to the top of the file:

```
IF EXIST *.avi || *.mp4
```

But I don't know if I can use the OR command like that and I don't know how to assign the filename to a variable and how to use that variable in the mediainfo.exe line.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%A in ("C:\folder\*.mp4" "C:\folder\*.avi") Do Echo %%A
```

To see it work listing ini files in Windows (NB interactively you use `%A` not `%%A` in batch). Paste the below.

```
for %A in (%windir%\*.ini) do Echo %~tA %~aA %A
```

See `for /?`.

**NB** this line does nothing `sleep 1`. Use `Waitfor`, `timeout`, or `choice`. See each one's help - `waitfor /?`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Noodles.  This works for me.  I just append the f:\path\mediainfo.exe... command to the end of the for command instead of Echo and it works.  I needed the SLEEP command because when I was running this script last night the output file wasn't being generated instantaneously.  Adding that delay gave it time to be created and then open in Notepad.  I guess my CPU was being hammered by some of the background programs running.  The file is opening instantaneously this morning.